# C# object equals int doesn't equal true

Tags: c#

I have a very simple if statement but it always returns false never true.
Here is my if statement

```
if (objectValue.Equals(intValue))
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Do I need to cast my objectValue variable to an int before comparing them?

Comment: what is objectValue?

Comment: `((object)3).Equals(3)` returns `true`, so you're having a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Also: what is `objectValue.GetType().FullName` ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Equals` is a virtual method it will call the appropriate method of the subclass of `object`. In this case `int.Equals`. In a very simple example:

```
object o = 4;
int i = 4;
```

`o.Equals(i)` returns `true`. So your problem is somewhere else. Maybe objectValue is not an `int`, but a `byte`, `short` or other numerical type.

Comment: Thank you Joey that is correct, basically I have now updated to cast it to an int so it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with having the `int` boxed in an object - that works just fine, as you can easily try yourself.

The problem only appears when the `object` doesn't actually contain an `int`, but rather a different numerical type, e.g. `short` or `byte` - in that case, you have to first unbox it to the correct type (for example, `(short)objectValue`) and *then* do the comparison. Unboxing a boxed `short` to `int` results in `InvalidCastException` - you have to use the exact type with value-types.

Also, there's usually no need to use `Equals` for that - just do `(int)objectValue == intValue` or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
int val;
if (int.TryParse(objectValue.ToString(), out val))
{
    if (val == intValue)
    {
        // return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //return false;
    }
}
else
{
    // value of obj is not int. you know here something is wrong
}
```

Using `TryParse()` method would be safer option even if you have non int value in the objectValue.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to cast it

```
return ((int)objectValue).Equals(intValue);
```

without the cast a type comparison will be performed and object is never equal to an int, thats why you get the false value.

Comment: Nope. Equals is overriden in `Integer`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals(v=vs.110).aspx  , Think you should read the manual, if object.equals(othertype) it checks to see if it is same type , in this case it is not

Comment: I think you should read about virtual and overriden members. When you call `Equals` of object which real type is int, `Equals` from `Integer` is called but not from `Object` - due to inheritance and overriden virtual member.

Comment: Well in this case in the original question the object is not an int and I answered why he Always got the false result on the equals call.